# vim-dadbod with Azure sql uses SQLCMD with quotes that break it

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

Greetings Vim Experts!

I'm using gVim on windows 10, and installing the plugin [vim-dadbod](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dadbod) to work with Azure SQL (SQL Server).  I believe the plugin is installed correctly as I see the connection string being turned into a SQLCMD in a pop-up window.  The final command that vim-dadbod creates is using single quotes for all of the parameters & I think that is what is wrong.  If I type out the same SQLCMD without the quotes (in a CMD window), it works.  Has anyone had similar issues using vim-dadbod with SQL Server?

The manual connection string that works from a CMD window is:

> `sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME.database.windows.net -U USERNAME -d DBNAME -q "select name from sys.tables"`

The command (copied from a screenshot) being generated from vim-dadbod is:

> `cmd.exe /c (^(sqlcmd -S 'SERVERNAME.database.windows.net' -U 'USERNAME' -P 'PASSWORD' -d 'DBNAME'^) ^< C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Temp/VIiF7B1.tmp ^>C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Temp/VIoF7B2.tmp 2^>^&1)`

I assume the tmp files are for the actual query and returned results, but that's just a guess.

If I manually type out the SQLCMD with single quotes I get the same highly generic error as from vim-dadbod; which is:
[image: vim Error]
Curious since I'm not using ODBC, never mind Named Pipes...

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! :-)

Comment: @filbranden you gave good advice :)

Comment: Do you have [`'shellslash'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shellslash%27) enabled? Check it with `:set ssl?`. I ask because it seems this option affects the behavior of [`shellencode()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29) on Windows...

Comment: @filbranden Wow, yes I did!  It's in the Vundle setup... :(   I turned it off and now I get connections.  In a stand-alone SQLCMD window; not really what I was expecting, and considerably underwhelming.  Is vim-dadbod-ui the missing link to being able to run code that's in my vim window?
P.S.  Ordered a Macbook Pro with the new M1 chip today...  maybe I can use that for work instead :D

Answer (score 1):

In gVim (on Windows) the setup code for the package manager *Vundle* uses the command `set shellslash` in _vimrc.

This setting messes up the formatting of the command being sent to SQLCMD by vim-dadbod.  By adding `set noshellslash` further down in the .vimrc (_vimrc on Windows) vim-dadbod then works.

Many thanks to @filbranden who suggested that was the issue!

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer that solved for you! I checked a bit on Vundle and `'shellslash'` and I don't really see a requirement for it (on the contrary, I found some posts complaining that Vundle *didn't* work with it.) You usually need `'shellslash'` when you're using a POSIX shell on a Windows platform. One example is "Git BASH", which is a build of the `bash` shell that comes bundled with a Git distribution for Windows. Otherwise, you don't need it. I'm glad disabling it after Vundle is working well for you!

Comment: As a general suggestion (and I believe I already mentioned it in another question of yours), I usually recommend [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as a more modern, well maintained alternative to Vundle. vim-plug has more features and better performance (by using more efficient git checkouts and performing operations in parallel.) Yet, it uses a similar execution model to Vundle and very similar commands, so it should be mostly familiar for users upgrading from Vundle. I really recommend it as a replacement!

Comment: Thanks again @filbranden  Yes, vim-plug is much easier to understand :) and I was able to get it running without Windows time-bombs like `shellslash`.  vim-dadbod is working and it is everything I hoped for.  All my SQL development can now be done interactively from Vim.

Comment: Excellent news @norton64, glad everything is working well for you. Thanks for the update!